# How do I delete duplicate rows and keep the row with higher value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 4 key fields. A1(primary key), A2, A3, A4.

I'd like to remove duplicate in A3 where A4 is lower.

Ex. 
A3 Values  G258 - G258
A4 Values  1000 - 1500

Remove the record where A3 = G258 and A4 is 1000 (lower)

How I can do?

Comment: what do you mean with *duplicates in `A3` where `A4` is lower*?

Comment: A3 values : G123 G123
A4 values : 100 150
I'd like to remove G123 at 100

Comment: Your title and your question are not consistent. In the title you want to "keep the row with lower value". In your question and the comment you want to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete t1 
from some_table t1
join some_table t2
  on  t2.a3 = t1.a3
  and t2.a4 > t1.a4;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/RERGD32491

This will only keep rows with the highest value in `A4` per `A3`. It's possible that two rows with the same value in `A3` have the same highest value in `A4`. Since you didn't specify what to do in that case - Both rows will be kept.